Bruhat decomposition of $SL_3$
I would like to know the Bruhat decomposition of $SL_3$.
In Chevalley Group Theory, we have the following theorem:
Let $G$ be the Chevalley group, and $G=\langle\mathfrak{X}_\alpha | \alpha \;\text{are} roots \rangle$. Then
$$
\bigcup_{w\in W}BwB=G.
$$
Where $B$ is generated by $U$ and $H$, and $U = \mathfrak{X}_P, P=\{\alpha \; \text{are roots}|\alpha > 0\}$,$H$ is generated by all $h_\alpha(t)$.
$h_\alpha(t)=w_\alpha(t)w_\alpha(1)^{-1}.$
$w_\alpha(t)=x_\alpha(t)x_{-\alpha}(-t^{-1})x_\alpha(t)$
$\mathfrak{X}_\alpha= \{x_\alpha(t)= \exp(tx_\alpha)\}$
For $SL_3$, its Borel subgroup $B$ is all upper triangular matrices with determinant 1, and the Weyl group is isomorphic to $S_3$, corresponding to permutation matrices:$\{e, s_1, s_2, s_1s_2, s_2s_1, s_1s_2s_1\}$.
$$
SL_3=\bigcup_{w\in W}BwB.
$$
we have the following double coset representatives：
$$
\begin{aligned}
&1.B\cdot e\cdot B \\
&2.B\cdot s_1\cdot B \\
&3.B\cdot s_2\cdot B \\
&4.B\cdot s_1s_2\cdot B \\
&5.B\cdot s_2s_1\cdot B \\
&6.B\cdot s_1s_2s_1\cdot B
\end{aligned}
$$
We can calculate them separately, which is not difficult.
I'm not sure if the above results are correct, anyway, I hope to understand $SL_3$ from this decomposition. Taking it a step further, I would like to ask what profound implications this decomposition has in the Chevalley group. And what does it have to do with the Reductive Groups.
What is the use of this decomposition in the representation of algebraic groups or the representation theory of Lie algebras, and how to analyze it in this example ?
Looking forward to your reply, thank you!

I'm not so familiar with the Chevalley group story but it might be helpful to understand the Lie group one. In that case, the Bruhat decomposition of $SL_3$ is just the LUP decomposition. One of the main results of this decomposition is the Schubert cell decomposition of the corresponding flag manifolds.

@Callum Thank you. I also noticed that it has something to do with Schubert cell. I'll find out about it.
